# How do I convert data in dictionary format from a url into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

This is the address that contains the data I am looking to convert into a dataframe: https://oec.world/olap-proxy/data?cube=trade_i_baci_a_92&Exporter+Country=nausa&HS4=42204&Year=2016&drilldowns=Importer+Country&locale=en&measures=Trade+Value&parents=true&sparse=false&properties=Importer+Country+ISO+3&q=Trade%20Value

I want the headers to be Continent ID, Continent, Country ID, Country and so on. How do i go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

requests and pandas json_normalize do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

URL='https://oec.world/olap-proxy/data?cube=trade_i_baci_a_92&Exporter+Country=nausa&HS4=42204&Year=2016&drilldowns=Importer+Country&locale=en&measures=Trade+Value&parents=true&sparse=false&properties=Importer+Country+ISO+3&q=Trade%20Value'

content = requests.get(URL)

d = content.json() # parses json
print(d.keys()) # shows the keys containing the data

df=pd.json_normalize(d['data']) # converts json data into dataframe
print(df.head())
```

output:

```
dict_keys(['data', 'source'])
  Continent ID Continent Country ID        Country ISO 3  Trade Value
0           af    Africa      afago         Angola   ago      57107.0
1           af    Africa      afben          Benin   ben     928821.0
2           af    Africa      afbfa   Burkina Faso   bfa       6998.0
3           af    Africa      afciv  Cote d'Ivoire   civ      55066.0
4           af    Africa      afcmr       Cameroon   cmr      53461.0
```